# function to sort each array, and then compare

Tags: c#, visual-studio

how i can i improve this array so they compare in the same order. I'm comparing two arrays

enter code here

```
    static bool CompareArray(int[] a, int[] b)
      {
        bool areLenghtsEqual = a.Length == b.Length;

        if (!areLenghtsEqual)
        {
            return false;
        }



        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same order"?  I don't even see any code to check if the array elements are equal.  Do you mean you want your function to sort each array, and then compare?

Comment: yes that what i met

Comment: That is needlessly complicated. The entire function body could be replaced with just `return a.Length == b.Length;`

Answer (score -1):

Sorting an array in C# is simple, especially if all you need is an int array sorted from smallest to greatest...

`Array.Sort(yourIntArrayA);`

You can then compare like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourIntArrayA.Length; i++)
{
    if (yourIntArrayA[i] == yourIntArrayB[i])
        // your logic here
}
```

If you want something more complicated, you can create a custom array class and override the `==` operator or use a List.

Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2)